# java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key D:\<file path and name> (error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line)

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I'm writing about a newly issued TrustCor SSL certificate I downloaded recently from my NoIP account.
I went through the entire process of generating key pairs, creating a certificate request, downloading the pem-chain file, and importing it to my keystore file which I named "rickcygnusx1.ddns.net". I configured my Tomcat server's server.xml file to use the newly created pem file containing the certificates. However, when I started it, I got this error message:
"java.lang.Exception: Unable to load certificate key D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\rickcygnusx1_ddns_net.pem (error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line)"

I have turned the internet upside down and backwards to find a solution, including making sure the certificates in the chain file start with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and end with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", changing the file's extension from pem-chain to .pem, making sure the text format is ascii, adding "\n" to the end of the lines, tried both 443 and 8443 ports, but always get the same error message.
Please let me know if you guys can help in anyway, or if there's somewhere I should look that I haven't tried yet.
I host my java/jsp based website on my own Windows 10 laptop. I currently use eclipse IDE 2022-06 with Tomcat 9 and Java 17

Here are the commands I executed during the process:

- keytool -genkey -alias xxxxxx -keyalg RSA -keystore
  d:\rickcygnusx1.ddns.net

note: When prompted to enter my first and last name, I entered my domain name instead, according to NoIP instructions

- keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias xxxxxx -file d:\csr.txt -keystore
  d:\rickcygnusx1.ddns.net
- keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -v -alias xxxxxx -file
  d:\rickcygnusx1_ddns_net.pem-chain -keystore d:\rickcygnusx1.ddns.net

Here's my server.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener"/>
 <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" useAprConnector="true"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
 <GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
 </GlobalNamingResources>
 <Service name="Catalina">
  <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" discardFacades="true" maxThreads="100" port="443"
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true">
   <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
   <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate    certificateFile="D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\rickcygnusx1_ddns_net.pem"
                    certificateKeyFile="D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\rickcygnusx1_ddns_net.pem"
                    certificateChainFile="D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.40\conf\rickcygnusx1_ddns_net.pem"
                    hostName="rickcygnusx1.ddns.net"/>
   </SSLHostConfig>
  </Connector>
   <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>
    <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
     <Context docBase="cygnusx1" path="/" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:cygnusx1"/>
    </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Thanks in advance

10/3

updated connector tag in response to Dave Thompson's post:

```
  <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" discardFacades="true" maxThreads="100" port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true"
    defaultSSLHostConfigName="rickcygnusx1.ddns.net">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="rickcygnusx1.ddns.net">
     <Certificate   certificateKeystoreFile="d:\rickcygnusx1.ddns.net"
                    certificateKeystorePassword="xxxxxxx"
                    certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12"
                    certificateKeyAlias="xxxxxx" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
  </Connector>
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome! I hope you just forgot to mention, but you *copied* the .pems to correct folder!?

Comment: Thank you! yes I did, at least I hope, I put the pem-chain file on Tomcat's "conf" folder, and changed the extension to .pem

Comment: This is not programming or development, but your PEM file from the CA contains only certificates NOT the privatekey and so cannot be used for certificateKeyFile. **Either extract the privatekey from the keystore** to PEM, which you can do with `openssl pkcs12` as Java 9 up (including 17) keytool creates PKCS12, **or in Tomcat 8.5 up (including 9) you can use the keystore file** even for APR with `certificateKeyStoreFile` and no other file(s), only optionally -KeyStoreType and -KeyAlias. PS `hostName` should be on the `SSLHostConfig`, although with only one it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks so much Dave!!! perfect instructions, the errors are gone!! I will paste the updated connector tag on my first post above (the rest of the file stays the same). I also had to use the defaultSSLHostConfigName attribute because it was giving me error messages. Unfortunately there's a new problem, my Microsoft Edge browser absolutely refuses to open my website on the secure link, saying that my IP address (with the SSL port) "refused to connect". I updated the port number on my NoIP account, added the SSL port to the monitored ports list on Eclipse, but so far no site. I'll keep you posted